# Hibernate. Why entities queried from database are stored in a collection in random order?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a mysql database with 4 tables with one to many relationship. All the rows of the tables are stored in the correct order, but when I query the data with Hibernate, I get it in random order.(in Set collection). Has anybody encounted such issue?

Comment: Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Set` is not designed to keep the insertion order of elements.
`LinkedHashSet` is the exception.
But Hibernate doesn't use this implementation as you declare a `OneToMany` relationship with a `Set` such as :

```
@OneToMany(...)
Set<MyEntity> entities;
```

To solve your issue, replace your `Set` by a `List` in the mapping of the `OneToMany` relationship :

```
@OneToMany(...)
List<MyEntity> entities;
```